# Login using passport JS and mongoDB fails when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, passport.js

I've built a simple app using node and express. The app uses passport JS as a login system and the login credentials are stored in MongoDB Atlas. Everything works perfect when I run the app locally. However, when I upload it to Heroku, everything seems fine until I try to login. When I enter my login detials and click submit I get "internal server error" in the browser. I can't think of any logical reason why this wouldn't work. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks

The logs in heroku show the following (I've edited the url for privacy reasons)

> 

2021-06-22T16:11:25.958314+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)

2021-06-22T16:11:25.958316+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

2021-06-22T16:11:25.958705+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mPOST /login [31m500[0m 10010.055 ms - 148[0m

2021-06-22T16:11:25.961104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login" host=boiling-wave-*****.herokuapp.com request_id=99b8a8c6-87ef-464b-ab7a-78faa3808cb8 fwd="176.24.39.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10013ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https

2021-06-22T16:12:41.330390+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

2021-06-22T16:12:41.330401+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout. (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)

2021-06-22T16:12:41.330402+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)

2021-06-22T16:12:41.330404+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2021-06-22T16:12:41.330390+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: Operation
> users.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms
>
> 2021-06-22T16:12:41.330401+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout.
> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:197:23)

Your mongodb connection to get your user using the credentials you entered is timing out. Check that it's running and accessible from your Heroku instance; if it was running on your localhost machine before, it probably won't be reachable from Heroku's cloud.

Additionally, you probably want to add some logging or response handling to your app to catch those errors and print something more useful to your users if you feel that the default 500 page is too inscrutable. Be careful not to reveal too much, though, if this is going to be a public application.

Comment: How would I check if it's accessible from my Heroku instance? It works when i run it locally using "npm start" and when I use "heroku local web"

Comment: I have no experience with MongoDB Atlas, but I would hope that if it works locally against the same Atlas instance, then it would work from Heroku's servers, as long as you have both IP addresses allowed to connect; see https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/use-atlas-on-heroku/#step-5--grant-authorized-ip-addresses-access-to-your-cluster

Do you have any platform-specific environment variables or configuration (e.g. `.env` files) that may differ between environments? Are you running a local MongoDB instance as well, or another Atlas node for development on a different host/port?

Comment: You were right, only my personal IP address was allowed to connect. I've got it fixed now. Thanks!